# Reactive Observable Subscription Disposal

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

If I have access to an IObservable that I know is only ever going to return one item, will this work and is it the best usage pattern?

```
IDisposable disposable = null;
disposable = myObservable.Subscribe(x =>
  {
     DoThingWithItem(x);
     if (disposable != null)
     {
       disposable.Dispose();
     }
  });
```

Comment: IMHO the fact that a disposed object is in scope makes it a bad style. Am I missing something?

Comment: By this, do you mean that the "disposable" variable could be disposed of if myObservable fires before the disposable variable goes out of scope?  What is a better pattern to dispose of this object?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm also still learning Rx. So I'm not really an expert but I believe the disposable returned by `Subscribe` will only unsubscribe the subscription. Also if the source completes, like in your case, the unsubscription is done automatically. So I think the `Dispose` there is redundant and can be safely removed.

See the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053832/rx-disposing-a-subscription) for more info.

Answer (score 71):

The disposable returned by the `Subscribe` extension methods is returned solely to allow you to manually unsubscribe from the observable **before** the observable naturally ends.

If the observable completes - with either `OnCompleted` or `OnError` - then the subscription is already disposed for you.

Try this code:

```
var xs = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
{
    var d = Observable.Return(1).Subscribe(o);
    return Disposable.Create(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed!");
        d.Dispose();
    });
});

var subscription = xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

If you run the above you'll see that "Disposed!" is written to the console when the observable completes without you needing call `.Dispose()` on the subscription.

One important thing to note: the garbage collector never calls `.Dispose()` on observable subscriptions, so you **must** dispose of your subscriptions if they have not (or may not have) naturally ended before your subscription goes out of scope.

Take this, for example:

```
var wc = new WebClient();

var ds = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<
        DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler,
        DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(
            h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted += h,
            h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= h);

var subscription =
    ds.Subscribe(d =>
        Console.WriteLine(d.EventArgs.Result));
```

The `ds` observable will only attach to the event handler when it has a subscription and will only detach when the observable completes or the subscription is disposed of. Since it is an event handler the observable will never complete because it is waiting for more events, and hence disposing is the only way to detach from the event (for the above example).

When you have a `FromEventPattern` observable that you know will only ever return one value then it is wise to add the `.Take(1)` extension method before subscribing to allow the event handler to automatically detach and then you don't need to manually dispose of the subscription.

Like so:

```
var ds = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<
        DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler,
        DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(
            h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted += h,
            h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= h)
    .Take(1);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have this exact issue (an event that I only want one of), and `Take(1)` is the perfect solution.

Comment: @moswald Note `FirstAsync()` does the same thing.

Comment: `the garbage collector never calls .Dispose() on observable subscriptions` - This is what I was here for. Thanks!

Comment: @Sebastian - I just wanted to make sure you understand that the garbage collector *never* calls `.Dispose()` on any object - there's nothing special about observable subscriptions.

Comment: Yeah, but I wondered if the specific implementation had a finalizer which would call `Dispose()`.

Comment: @Sebastian - It doesn't. But also remember that there is no guarantee that a finalizer will ever run. You need to ensure you explicitly call `.Dispose()` if it is important that it is called.

Comment: So, we need to call `subscription.Dispose()` to *detach from the event* (I mean the observable `FromEventPattern`)?

Comment: @zwcloud - Yes, that's precisely why subscriptions return an `IDisposable`. Although, a `.Take(1)` will automatically detach from the event after the first value is returned.

Comment: `it is wise to add the .Take(1) extension method before subscribing to allow the event handler to automatically detach` - What a legend, Thanks!

Comment: Amazing answer, dude.

Answer (score 6):

In contrast to some comments it's not at all uncommon to dispose of a subscription from inside `OnNext`.
While it's true that disposal at `OnCompleted` and `OnError` are done for you by a wrapped subscription that the `Subscribe` extension method creates, you may want to unsubscribe based on a value you're observing (like in your case: the 1st one). You don't always have an observable that is known to produce only one value.
Problem is that you get the `IDisposable` only after you have subscribed. An observable may call you back on `OnNext` even before it returns you the `IDisposable` to unsubscribe (depending on things like the `IScheduler` it uses).
The `System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable` comes in handy in this case. It wraps an `IDisposable` that you may assign late, and will immediately dispose it on assignment if the `SingleAssignmentDisposable` already has been disposed by then. Also it carries a property `IsDisposed` which initially is `false` and is set to `true` when `Dispose()` is called.

So:

```
IObservable<string> source = ...;

var subscription = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
subscription.Disposable = source.Subscribe(x =>
{
    if (subscription.IsDisposed) // getting notified though I've told it to stop
        return;
    DoThingsWithItem(x);
    if (x == "the last item I'm interested in")
        subscription.Dispose();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Take` function will do exactly what you are looking for.  In this case, `Take(1)`.

Comment: What you say can be proven?