# Is it possible to subscribe to an IObservable<T> with a single method?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive

I have a class that exposes a IObservable. This is how:

```
  private readonly Subject<(int moduleNumber, int channelNumber, object oldValue, object newValue)> _channelChanged =
        new Subject<(int moduleNumber, int channelNumber, object oldValue, object newValue)>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribe to this if you want to be notified as soon as a channel changed its value.
    /// </summary>
    public IObservable<(int moduleNumber, int channelNumber, object oldValue, object newValue)> ChannelChanged => _channelChanged.AsObservable();
```

I created an instance of this class an tried to subscribe to this IObservable like this:

```
 public void TestDataModelEventWhenAnalogueChannelChanged()
    {
        var instance = new MyClassThatContainsTheIObservable();

        IDisposable subscription = instance.ChannelChanged.Subscribe(OnChannelChanged);

        // do stuff that leads to a channel changing its value
    }

    private void OnChannelChanged((int moduleNumber, int channelNumber, object oldValue, object newValue) e)
    {
        // Assert the correct arguments appear here
    }
```

The compiler says that he can't convert from a method group to an IObserver. I get that - intellisense tells me that I need to provide an IObserver to Subscribe(). But then I found this tutorial:

https://rehansaeed.com/reactive-extensions-part1-replacing-events/

If you look at his example of subscribing you see that he just provides a method as well.
Looking at the answer of the following question it seems to be possible to subscribe with a lambda-expression, as well:

[Reactive Observable Subscription Disposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703366/reactive-observable-subscription-disposal)

When trying this, my compiler tells me the same: He can't convert a lambda expression to IObserver.

What am I doing wrong? Do I really have to create a whole class that implements IObserver?

Comment: I can compile your code without problem, using C# 8 and VS 2019.

Comment: But that shouldn't be a VS or C#-Version issue? I installed System.Reactive v4.3.1 via NuGet.

Comment: I don't know if it's a version issue. I am just reporting that I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Missing using System.Reactive. Or using Sustem.Reactive.Linq.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you've missed `using System;`. The `Subscribe` extension which accepts an action is defined in the `System` namespace, because `IObservable` itself is defined in that namespace.